# Context Free Grammar for a language

Tags: context-free

I have a language L = {a^n b^m c^k | n = m or m != k}
When I was working the problem out this is what I got:

S -> S1|S2

S1 -> AC
A -> aAb|$\lambda$
C -> Cc |$\lambda$

S2 -> BD
B -> aB|$\lambda$
D -> bDcc|E
E -> Ecc|$\lambda$

I feel like this is right but at the same time I am not too certain it is. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Looks to me like the grammar won't generate $abbc$. You're on the right track, though: think of three starts: one like your $S1$ to generate the $n=m$ part, one to generate the $m<k$ part and one for the $m>k$ part.

Comment: Yes, rules for D and E generate a language smaller than required.

Comment: It looks like you might have accidentally created two accounts.  I encourage you to [merge them](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), to ensure you retain ability to edit and comment on your own question.